# Aligning and fitting bg image to iOS screen

Tags: ios

I would like to place a background image on an iOS screen so that the left, top and right edges will align with respective edges of the screen. What is the way to do so?

[image: iOS screen]

Comment: Why is it tagged as "android" if it's an iOS question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- In Interface Builder or your Storyboard, set the **View > Mode** (or `contentMode`) of the `UIImageView` to *AspectFill* (or *AspectFit*, whatever you like better)

[image]

- then open up the AutoLayout "Pin" Settings and click on the red dotted lines to pin your view to the nearest neighbor; the lines get solid. Then select "**Add 4 Contraints**":

[image]

Usually, this is the surrounding view, but it might be different from case to case.

Finally, to test quickly if this works as expected without having to compile and run, select the corresponding viewController (still in the Storyboard) and select a different **Size** or **Orientation** in the **Simulated Metrics** section.

---

For a deeper understanding of AutoLayout, I recommend watching a WWDC video about AutoLayout (e.g. Mysteries of AutoLayout Part 1 and 2 of WWDC 2015): https://developer.apple.com/videos/

Comment: Checking Aspect Ratio improves your solution.

Comment: Good point! Depends on the content mode, though: E.g. for Aspect Fit definitely, not so much for Aspect Fill.

Answer (score 0):

```
imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleToFill
```